# Why did I get very low negative SNR value of White Gaussian noise I added into a image

Tags: image, image-processing, noise

I'm using the following code to add white Gaussian noise to a 3D synthetic image I created. (100*100*100)

```
   sigma = sqrt(10.0^(-snr/10.0)); 
   r=x+sigma*randn(size(x));
```

I found that different ways of adding the noise need different range of SNR value.
eg. if I add noise stack by stack (x=image stack), the original image become invisible until SNR goes down to -50.
but when I try to add noise straight away in 3D, (x=3D image). the original image become invisible until SNR goes down to -5.
I've looked up everywhere but couldn't found solution of what causing this...could anyone please tell me if it's normal to have a 3D noisy image with SNR=-50dB or even -70dB? Or is there any way to know the true SNR of my noisy images?